# Swift Generic does not show nil

Tags: swift, codable

I have following general structure where `data` can be anyother codable object

```
struct GeneralResponse<T:Codable>: Codable {
    let message: String
    let status: Bool
    let data: T?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case message = "Message"
        case status = "Status"
        case data = "Data"
    }

}
```

I have Following Like response codable class which will be used as `data` in `GeneralResponse`

```
class ImgLike: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let imageID, user: String?

    @available(*, deprecated, message: "Do not use.")
    private init() {
        fatalError("Swift 4.1")
    }
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "ID"
        case imageID = "ImageID"
        case user = "User"
    }

}
```

**Question 1** : When the token expires on API, The response `data` is empty `{}` still It show `ImgLike` object with all nil properties. Why it not show data to be nil ?

[image]

Then If I check object?.data == nil it is showing false !! So I need to check each property

**Question 2** : In **ImgLike** If I am using custom encode function.  `GeneralResponse` not parsed with `ImgLike` not parsed  it shows error in catch statement

```
required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    imageID =  try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .imageID)
    user = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .user)

    do {
        id = Int(try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id))

    } catch {
        id = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The equivalents of Swift-`nil` are JSON-`null` and JSON-`not-set`. `{}` is a valid dictionary in JSON and so not Swift-`nil`.
2. I guess that you mean that you get an error incase you use the custom decoder function? That‘s expected since the default decoder uses `decodeIfPresent` instead of `decode` to decode optionals since they are allowed not to be set.
   And since you decode an empty dictionary `{}` none of the values are present/set.

#### Counting keys in dict to avoid decoding from JSON-`{}`

This `CodingKey`-struct accepts every key it gets.

```
fileprivate struct AllKeysAllowed: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int?
    init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }
    init?(intValue: Int) {
        self.intValue = intValue
        stringValue = "\(intValue)"
    }
}

struct GeneralResponse<T:Codable>: Decodable {
    let message: String
    let status: Bool
    let data: T?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case message = "Message"
        case status = "Status"
        case data = "Data"
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        message = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
        status = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .status)
```

Decode `.data` to a container which had all keys accepted.
Then the number of keys in the `JSON-dictionary` is readable with `dataContainer.allKeys.count`.

```
        let dataContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AllKeysAllowed.self, forKey: .data)
        if dataContainer.allKeys.count != 0 {
            data = try container.decode(T.self, forKey: .data)
        } else {
            data = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **The equivalents of nil in Swift are null and not-set in JSON. {} is a valid dictionary in JSON and so not nil.** Yes you are right {} is not nil it is empty. BUT I have decoded ImgLike that should be nil with empty {}. even though T in general response is optional

Comment: ***BUT I have decoded ImgLike that should be nil with empty {}.***: The only case where ***`data` can be nil*** is, when `“data“: {}` is ___not present___ in JSON. You can make `ImgLike`‘s attributes non-optional, then decoding `ImgLike` throws an error which you can handle with a `required init(from:)` in `GeneralResponse`  by ignoring the parsing error by catching and ignoring the error of it.

Comment: Scratch the do-catch part. I added a solution.

Comment: Thank you I will try it soon

Answer (score 0):

Note that the default `Codable` implementation uses `decodeIfPresent` instead of `decode`. `decodeIfPresent` will not throw an error even if the key is not present in the JSON. It will simply return `nil`. So an empty JSON dictionary has no KVPs, so all the properties are set to `nil`.

In your custom implementation of `Codable`, you are using `decode`, which *will* throw an error if the key is not found.

The reason why `object?.data != nil` is because `object?.data` is a `ImgLike???`. You are wrapping an optional in an optional in an optional. I see that the type of `object` is `GeneralResponse<ImgLike?>?`. This will make `data`'s type be `ImgLike??`. I don't think this is your intention. You probably intended to use `GeneralRepsonse<ImgLike>`. You might have forgotten to unwrap an optional somewhere. You also need to unwrap the outermost optional:

```
if let nonNilObject = object {
   // nonNilObject.data is of type ImgLike?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned the decoder does not treat an empty dictionary as `nil`.

You can add this functionality in a generic way with a tiny protocol and an extension of `KeyedDecodingContainer`

```
public protocol EmptyDictionaryRepresentable {
    associatedtype CodingKeys : RawRepresentable where CodingKeys.RawValue == String
    associatedtype CodingKeyType: CodingKey = Self.CodingKeys
}

extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    public func decodeIfPresent<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer.Key) throws -> T?
        where T : Decodable & EmptyDictionaryRepresentable
    {
        guard contains(key) else { return nil }
        let container = try nestedContainer(keyedBy: type.CodingKeyType.self, forKey: key)
        return container.allKeys.isEmpty ? nil : try decode(T.self, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Just add `EmptyDictionaryRepresentable` conformance to `ImgLike`, the associated types are inferred.

```
class ImgLike: Codable, EmptyDictionaryRepresentable {
```

The properties in `ImgLike` could be even declared as non-optional